# Why does my IsDate() If statement ignore "31/12/1019"

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to remove all dates before a certain time period, as well as anything that is not a date from my data set. I have roughly 4000 entries in column A dating back the last 10 years, with some typo's mixed in. There are no blanks spots between the data.

I have cobbled together the below code, which almost works. However there is one entry `31/12/1019` which is not being picked up as an old date, or a typo.

```
Sub deleterows()
    lastRow = Sheets("ConData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    bankingDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsDate(Cells(i, 1)) = False Or _
           Cells(i, 1).Value <= bankingDate Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Debug.Print (IsDate("31/12/1019"))` spits out "True" for me.

Comment: @JNevill yup did more research.  working on workaround now

Comment: @ScottCraner Beautiful!

Comment: Whenever you deal with dates convert them to double otherwise errors may arise in [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885692/vba-filter-by-date)

Comment: @Sgdva - how would you convert the string `"31/12/1019"` to a double?

Comment: Either declare it before as Date  `Dim d As Date: Dim n As Double d = "31/12/1019": n = CDbl(d)` or using a dateserial and reverse the string back to a date in the cdbl (which is the best imho)

Comment: Either way, you're converting it to a date first. Why would you then convert it to a Double, when you can already do math with dates? Your blanket recommendation is ... suspect.

Comment: That is why I linked the question, just an example of many that I have had due to let excel interpreter to assume the month, day, year on a given text date. Another example is when dealing with [DateDiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482958/vba-datediff-function-is-not-working-properly). Doing the cdbl() will prevent so many headaches down the road, it's easier to format as needed later on.

Comment: Perhaps there are some instances when it makes sense to convert to `CDbl`. But this is not one of them. That's an extra step entirely, and unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break it down, this is a wonderful inconsistency between Excel and VBA:

According to [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) article:

> In Windows, the range of valid dates is January 1, 100 A.D., through December 31, 9999 A.D.; the ranges vary among operating systems.

so IsDate will return TRUE for `31/12/1019`

But

Since Excel actually stores "dates" as a double with `1900-01-01` being `1.00` the date would be stored as a string in the worksheet and the `Cells(i, 1).Value <= bankingDate` would return `False` because a string is larger than a number.

But as @BigBen stated:

Cast to a date first before comparing to `bankingDate`.

```
If Not IsDate(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
   Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
ElseIf CDate(Cells(i, 1).Value) <= bankingDate
   Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, switched IsDate() to VarType() = vbString and it now works perfectly!

Comment: @Embie - well that's sort of different logic, as that will delete all text-that-look-like-dates. Unless that's what you want.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, you are right, It worked for me in this instance because the date was before my bankingDate, I'll change it over to CDATE.

Answer (score 0):

IsDate will give true but you can check then for
`isNumeric(Cells(i, 1).value2`
`If not IsDate(Cells(i, 1)) or not isNumeric(Cells(i, 1).value2) or ...`
Value2 gives a double for Date Cells which are later then 0.1.1900
And I believe your banking date will always be later